# I want fix tailwind css when i click buttton

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, webview, tailwind-css

I'm using Tailwind CSS in an ASP.NET project, and I have a button styled as follows:

```
<button class="mt-4 w-full default-org-btn close-btn active:bg-none active:outline-none">
    Đăng ký
</button>
```

The default-org-btn class is defined as:

```
@layer base {
    body {
        @apply text-[15px] font-sp-pro-regular text-[#070606] touch-manipulation;
    }

    button {
        @apply !shadow-none bg-transparent;
    }

    a {
        @apply !shadow-none bg-transparent;
    }
}


@layer components {
    .default-org-btn {
        @apply bg-[#f37021] h-[40px] leading-[40px] text-center text-white w-[234px] rounded-md outline-none shadow-none appearance-none;
    }
}
```

The issue is that when the button is pressed, it appears with a gray area. I'd like the button to maintain its original appearance before and after being pressed.

Here are images illustrating the button before and after it's pressed:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JA85.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YdY2M.png)

I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this behavior and maintain the button's original appearance even after being pressed. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

I'm looking for guidance on how to resolve this behavior and maintain the button's original appearance even after being pressed. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!"

Answer (score 0):

I tried to recreate a minimal reproducible example in a Tailwind Playground [here](https://play.tailwindcss.com/PjVzH7DpuL) and could not find the button changing during or after a click.

If what you mean happens on mobile, than maybe you a referring to [`tap-highlight-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-tap-highlight-color).